# Mongodb concurrency race condition

Tags: mongodb, transactions

I have similar codes belows:

```js
        let count = await Sample.countDocuments({});
        if (count < 5) {
            let result = await Sample.create({ name: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) });
        }
```

but the `count<5` condition will be useless in concurrency condition, the collection will allow insert more then 5 docs in it.

How can I solve this, and make sure the database will not create more then 5 docs on `Sample` Collection? Thanks!!

Comment: Use the `_id` field (which the database enforces to be unique) and set it to only the values 1,2,3,4 or 5. Or if you only have five documents, maybe you don't need a collection at all, just put all five into a single document somewhere (then you get to use atomic update operators if you must have them).

Comment: it is only the similar situation, for example the system to limit each user to create max 5 records for its own.

Comment: Then it is probably best to have only one document per user, and an array inside of that document to hold these five records.

Comment: Or do a two-phase commit: Check if you have less than 5, insert, then re-check if you have too many now and delete the excess.

Comment: I think the second solutions will work, but it will be better if the system can block them inserting before the ```count<5```.

Comment: Better for you? Maybe. But not better for the system/database. Scalability comes at a cost, distributed systems and concurrency are more complex to work with. Many features can only reasonably be implemented in the application layer. Maybe removing concurrency for this (serializing the inserts into a single queue) is also an option for you.